# Identify two hydrocarbons using volume and density

Tags: organic-chemistry, density, ideal-gas

**Question:**

> A gaseous mixture with volume 16.8 dm3 contains two unsaturated neighboring hydrocarbons belonging to the same group. Density of the mixture was 14.4 times as hydrogen gas.
>
> What could be the two hydrocarbons?
>
> (a) $\ce{CH4}$, $\ce{C2H6}$
>
> (b) $\ce{C2H2}$, $\ce{C3H4}$
>
> (c) $\ce{C3H4}$, $\ce{C4H6}$
>
> (d) $\ce{C3H6}$, $\ce{C4H9}$
>
> (e) none of the above

I'm not really sure how to approach this question. The answer according to the mark scheme is **b)**. What is the method to get this answer? Also, how can $\ce{C2H2}$ and $\ce{C3H4}$ be in the same group? One is an alkyne and the other a cycloalkene.

Comment: Read what you have written, the quoted task does not match your comment. $\ce{C2H2 means CH#CH}$, $\ce{C3H4 means CH3-C#CH}$, $\ce{C4H6 means CH3-CH2-C#CH}$

Comment: Some mixtures are too dense, and some aren't unsaturated.

Comment: @IvanNeretin All is allowed in incorrect answers. :-)

Comment: @Poutnik Fixed it. Oh right... I was thinking about cyclopropene for C3H4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The density of $\ce{H2}$ is such that $1$ mole, or $2$ g $\ce{H2}$ occupies a volume $22.4$ L at $0$°C at $1$ atm. Its density is $\pu{\frac{2 g}{22.4 L} = 0.0892 g/L}$.
Doing the same calculation with $\ce{C2H2}$ and $\ce{C3H4}$ gives densities equal to $\ce{1.1607}$ g/L for $\ce{C2H2}$ and $\pu{1.7857}$ g/L for $\ce{C3H4}$

The density of the gas mixture is $14.4 · 0.0892 = 1.2857$ g/L. This value is between the densities of $\ce{C2H2}$ and $\ce{C3H4}$. It means that these two gases can be mixed to give the observed density. So the choice b) can be an acceptable answer.

And indeed a mixture $80$% $\ce{C2H2}$ + $20$% $\ce{C3H4}$ has the observed density.

The solution c) contains too heavy hydrocarbons. The solution d) contains a non-existant compound ($\ce{C4H9}$)

Comment: But the question states the compounds have to be *unsaturated* so that answer can't be valid.

Comment: @matt_black. You are right. I edit my answer to take this remark into account.